# Creating defect with project or user as a vaiable

Tags: rest, rally

I'm trying to programatically create a defect.  When I pass the project or user fields as a variable to the JsonObject I get the following error:

Cannot parse object reference from ""/user/2.........""

Code:

```
newDefect.addProperty("SubmittedBy", username);
```

Where username = "/user/2........."

but if I have the following code:

```
newDefect.addProperty("SubmittedBy", "/user/2.........");
```

it passes.  I would like to be able to have the program dynamically look up the user and be able to get the reference, but so far when I have tried I get that error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code references to user and project are being passed as variables:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Rally.RestApi;
using Rally.RestApi.Response;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi("user@co.com", "secret", "https://rally1.rallydev.com", "v2.0");
        DynamicJsonObject user = restApi.GetCurrentUser();
        String userRef = user["_ref"];
        String workspaceRef = "/workspace/1111";
        String projectRef = "/project/3333";

        DynamicJsonObject myStory = new DynamicJsonObject();
        myStory["Name"] = "abc12345";
        myStory["Project"] = projectRef;
        myStory["Owner"] = userRef;
        CreateResult createResult = restApi.Create(workspaceRef, "HierarchicalRequirement", myStory);
        myStory = restApi.GetByReference(createResult.Reference, "FormattedID", "Owner", "Project");
        Console.WriteLine(myStory["FormattedID"] + " " + myStory["Owner"]._refObjectName + " " + myStory["Project"]._refObjectName);
    }
}
```